# Optimize Kmeans Clustering Code in Pyspark RDD

Tags: dictionary, optimization, pyspark, rdd, k-means

This is a very lengthy problem. This is my code for kmeans clustering. for 10 clusters it took me more than  an hour to compute the results.

Instead of using for and while loops as in my code, can I make the following code faster with RDD(map,flatmap,filter) etc? If so , where should I make the changes.

Here bj is an RDD with 30,000+ elements: The RDD used here is a collection of dictionaries. Each element can we identified with a key 'name' and all the other keys has a value[1,0] associated with it calculate the euclidean distance

Rdd content:

```
bj.collect():

[{'name': 'ab',
  'abc': 0,
  'def': 0,
  'ghi': 0,
  'jkl': 0,
  ....},
 {'name': 'ak',
  'abc': 1,
  'def': 1,
  'ghi': 0,
  'jkl': 0,
  ....},...]



from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql.session import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql import Row
import pyspark
import sys
from sys import argv
sc = SparkContext('local')
spark = SparkSession(sc)



all_states =["ab", "ak", "ar", "az", "ca", "co", "ct", "de", "dc", "fl",
         "ga", "hi", "id", "il", "in", "ia", "ks", "ky", "la", "me", "md",
         "ma", "mi", "mn", "ms", "mo", "mt", "ne", "nv", "nh", "nj", "nm",
         "ny", "nc", "nd", "oh", "ok", "or", "pa", "pr", "ri", "sc", "sd",
         "tn", "tx", "ut", "vt", "va", "vi", "wa", "wv", "wi", "wy", "al",
         "bc", "mb", "nb", "lb", "nf", "nt", "ns", "nu", "on", "qc", "sk",
         "yt", "dengl", "fraspm" ]


import random
random.seed(123)

init_states=random.sample(all_states, 3)

import math
centroids = bj.filter(lambda x: x['name'] in init_states)
ro=2
mon=0
mp=6
while(ro!=3):

#updating centroids after 1st cluster

    if(mp!=6):
        R=[]
        for i in range(len(jo)):
            j=jo[i][0]
            dc={}
            d1=bj.filter(lambda x: x['name']==j).first()

            for r in jo[i]:
                if(j!=r):
                    d2=bj.filter(lambda x: x['name']==r).first()
                    dc={key: d1[key] + d2[key] for key in d1.keys() if key not in {'name'} }
                    d1=dc
                if(j==r)&(len(jo[i])==1):
                    d2=bj.filter(lambda x: x['name']==r).first()
                    dc=d2
            dc={key: dc[key]/len(jo[i]) for key in dc.keys() if key not in {'name'} } 
            R.append(dc)
            R[i]['name']=init_states[i]


        centroids=sc.parallelize(R)

 #Clustering
    mp=3
    cent=centroids
    s={}
    r={}
    S=[]
    for i in all_states:
        mn=300000

        dc={}
        d1=bj.filter(lambda x: x['name']==i).first()
        for j in init_states:
            d2=centroids.filter(lambda x: x['name']==j).first()
            dc={key: (d1[key] - d2[key])**2 for key in d1.keys() if key not in 'name'}
            val=sum([v for v in dc.values()])
            val=math.sqrt(val)

            if(val<mn):
                s[i]=j
                mn=val

    k=[]
    for i in init_states:
        l=[]
        for j in all_states:
            if(s[j]==i):
                c=j
                l.append(c)

        k.append(sorted(l))
    jo=sorted(k)

    mon=mon+1
    if(mon>1):
        if(mu==jo):
            ro=3
    mu=jo


#print Cluster
lp=3;
for j in range(len(mu)):
    if(lp==3):
        print ("* Class",j)
    else:
        print("\n* Class",j)

    for i in mu[j]:
    lp=2
        print(i,'',end="")

print('')
```

Output:

```
* Class 0
ab bc mb mn qc sk 
* Class 1
ak dengl lb nt nu yt 
* Class 2
al fl ga ms nc sc 
* Class 3
ar ks ky la mo ok tn tx 
* Class 4
az ia nd ne sd 
* Class 5
ca co id mt nm nv or ut wa wy 
* Class 6
ct dc de il in ma md me mi nh nj ny oh on pa ri va vt wi wv 
* Class 7
fraspm nb nf ns 
* Class 8
hi 
* Class 9
pr vi
```